# jQuery modal opens with link also which I don't want

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using a jQuery modal from https://jquerymodal.com/ with 4th Example in it, but when I use that code and click on link the modal opens and also the link opens. I just want to open the modal, not the link because of the content in that link open in that modal.

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<a href="product.php?id=12" rel="modal:open" class="btn-primary btn-xss">Order</a>
```

Comment: As stated in the docs: *Create a link with rel="modal:open" and set the href attribute to the modal's DOM id.* You have it set to a URL.

Comment: Looking at Example 4, you may want to check `product.php?id=12` loads properly outside of the link.

Comment: you said was for the first example and i am talking about fourth

Comment: i dont want ouside brother .. what to do

Comment: Understandable, yet you will want to test the link and make sure it loads properly. This will help ensure that it loads that content to your modal element.

Comment: when I remove preloader, the modal works fine and when I use preloader it doesn't and I want both .. what should I want to do brother?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the link inside of  element:

```
<a rel="modal:open" class="btn-primary btn-xss">Order</a>
```

Comment: I want to open that link contents inside the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at their example: https://jquerymodal.com/ajax.html

It contains only the following:

```
<h1>Hello there!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Review your `product.php` and ensure that it is returning very basic HTML content. For example, when you navigate to `product.php?id=12`, it should return just the HTML you want to to appear in your modal:

**PHP**

```
<?php
// GET Request
$id = $_GET['id'];
// SQL Login and Query code here
// $product = array(name, desc)
$html = "<div class='product-title'>{$product['name']}</div>\r\n";
$html .= "<div class='product-desc'>{$product['desc']}</div>\r\n";
// Close SQL Connection
echo $html;
?>
```

This will help ensure you have the HTML output needed. Then in your HTML page you can run your code as expected:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<a href="product.php?id=12" rel="modal:open" class="btn-primary btn-xss">Order</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: my other jquery plugins are caused this .. what should i do to prevent that ??

Comment: my preloader cause this .. what to do